# How to start confluent platform?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

i have following problem

I am using java 8 version for this and zookeeper is not working for this.

```
Downloads$ cd confluent-5.2.2/

roshni@roshni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/confluent-5.2.2$ 

/home/roshni/Downloads/confluent-5.2.2/bin/confluent start





This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

WARNING: Java version 1.8 or 1.11 is recommended.
See https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html
```

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, your question header and description are not giving enough clarification?

Comment: Did you set the path? otherwise do `./confluent start`

Comment: yes i set path and this does not work.

Comment: "Confluent Kafka" isn't a thing. You're starting the entire Confluent Platform here

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct. Based on the warning, it seems to suggest you're not using Java 8 or 11, though, so check your JAVA_HOME variable, for example.

You could try running `confluent logs` to see if you get more information, and just do `confluent start kafka` if you're truly only trying to run Kafka

Otherwise, you could explicitly start Zookeeper and Kafka manually, as well as other Confluent services, using the other scripts in the bin folder, just the same as any other Kafka install